# Beyond Compare Ignore .SVN Folders From Java RAD SVN Subclipse

Tags: svn, beyondcompare, beyondcompare3

Is there a quick way to tell Beyond Compare to ignore the .svn folders inside of my comparisons?  It seems to be the only thing causing me headache showing bunch of red folders when only difference is in the .svn folders generated for my java code in Jboss Devloper Subclipse plugin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) You can type "-.svn\" in the filter edit in the toolbar.  You can also add that to the filter edit's dropdown list in the Options dialog.

2) If you load the home screen and expand the "Edit session defaults" node in the treeview, then select "Folder Compare", you can change the defaults used for all launched sessions.  Just add ".svn" to the "Name Filters" tab's "Exclude folders" edit.